# When and for how long was Jesus fully dwelling within the Father, reflecting the concept of 'full habitation' mentioned in John 14:20?

Tags: john, jesus

"How do the analysis of the preposition εν in John 14:20, the correlations with other biblical verses such as:

> Judges (A) 20:23, Judges (A) 21:7, 1 Samuel 2:1, 1 Samuel 10:22, 1 Samuel 23:2, 1 Samuel 24:22, 1 Samuel 28:6, 1 Samuel 30:6, 2 Samuel 2:1, 2 Samuel 19:8, 1 Kings 1:17, 1 Kings 1:30, 2 Kings 18:5, 2 Chronicles 20:20, 2 Chronicles 26:16, Psalm 20:8, Psalm 32:1, Isaiah 45:25, Hosea 1:7, Habakkuk 3:18, Zechariah 10:12, Zechariah 12:5.

as well as:

> John 1:18, John 10:15, John 14:10-11, 17, and 1 John 2:5, 1 John 2:24, 1 John 4:13, 1 John 4:16.

and the perspective of early Church fathers like Saint Basil in 'THE BOOK ON THE SPIRIT,' shed light on the duration and nature of Jesus' full habitation within the Father as suggested by the concept of 'full habitation'?"

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "in the Father" needs to be understood with a mystical ear rather than thinking of spatial or physical relations normally implied by the preposition "in." The disciples have asked Jesus to show them the Father. He responds by telling them "I and the Father are one" and proceeds to a discourse which includes the verse cited in the OP.

John 14:15-20

> If you love me, you will keep my commandments. 16 And I will ask the
> Father, and he will give you another Advocate to be with you always,
> 17 the Spirit of truth, which the world cannot accept, because it
> neither sees nor knows it. But you know it, because it remains with
> you, and will be in you. 18 I will not leave you orphans; I will come
> to you. 19 In a little while the world will no longer see me, but you
> will see me, because I live and you will live. 20 On that day you will
> realize that I am in my Father and you are in me and I in you. 21
> Whoever has my commandments and observes them is the one who loves me.
> And whoever loves me will be loved by my Father, and I will love him
> and reveal myself to him.”

To answer as directly as possible, Christ indwells the Father in the same way that we indwell Christ. It is not a one-way proposition but a give-and-take of love in which the Father, the Son, and each believer are mutual participants. This involves not only believing and being, but also keeping Christ's commandments. The mystical union of Christ and the Church is also implied here. In the end, Christ is one with both the Father and with us -- and vice versa.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: What is the force of Jesus' use of the preposition εν in John 14:20? (1 answer)